# Visual studio tag highlighting feature is missing!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I need a little assistance with regards to my visual studio IDE. There is this feature in aspx markup pages to highlight the matching tags when you click on them.

```
                            <td style="height: 25px" align="right">
                                Invoice Total:
                            </td>
```

e.g. the two td tags should be highlighted when i click on one of them.

My IDE seems to have messed up and that feature is no longer available. Anybody know how to activate it again? I tried some options in the Text Editor configuration but didnt really find a solution. Help is appreciated!

/Bumble Bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options. In Options window select TextEditor -> General. On right pane check "Automatic delimiter highlighting". this should help you.